# Using java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I´m not a programmer, so my level is newie in this field. I must create a regular expression to check two lines. Between these two lines A and B could be one, two or more different lines.

I´ve been reviewing link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html but i´ve not reach the solution, althouth i think that i´m very close to the solution.

I am testing the expression
`^(.*$)`
and this gets an entire line. If i write this expression twice it gets two lines. So it seems that this expression is getting as entire lines as occurrences of the expression.

But, i would like to check undetermined lines between A and B. I know that at least it will be one line
If i write `^(.*$){1,}` it doesn´t work.

Anyone knows which could be the mistake?

Thank you for your time
Andres

Comment: Regexes is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOT `.` in regex matches any character except newline character.

You're looking for [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) or `s` flag here that makes dot match any character including newline character as well. So if you want to match all the lines between literals `A and B` then use this regex:

```
(?s)A.*?B
```

`(?s)` is for DOTALL that will make `.*?` match all the characters including newline characters between A and B.

`?` is to make above regex non-greedy.

Read More: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Scanner ? It might be more related to what you want:

```
Scanner sc = new ...
while (sc.nextLine().compareTo(strB)!=0) {
whatYouWantToDo
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it inside java.util.regex Class Pattern?. I think that "my" application that will check the pattern only understand regular expressions based on this java class.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to search for line terminators `\r` and `\n`. Depending on the source of the file you maybe have to experiment a bit.
As far as I understood it, you want to match the lines, with at least one empty line in between? Try `^(.*)$\n{2,}^(.*)$`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find two equal lines, using regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:.*\n)*(.*\n)(?:.*\n)*\\1");
// Skip some lines, find a line, skip some lines, find the first group `(...)`
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Double: " + m.group(1);
}
```

The `(?: ...)` is a non-capturing group; that is, not available through `m.group(#)`.

However this won't find line B in: "A\nB\nA\nB\n".